# Recognizing group tags

Tags: php, algorithm, tags

I am not sure how to approach this problem - I have a list with players, e.g.

> - Player
> - Coco [infi]
> - booo #team
> - someone
> - Dabadee #team
> - goliat #team
> - stratder [infi]

Obviously, `Coco` and `stratder` have a team tag `[infi]` and `booo`, `goliat` and `Dabadee` have a tag called `#team`.

I want to list different tags, however a tag can be `<tag>` `#tag` `[tag]` or whatever people's (game) clan tags are (I am fetching the play data from a server).

I am not sure how to do it exactly, the best things I could thing of was:

- explode `" "`
- add every possible item from the explode into an array
- make it so the array shows only unique items
- count each string how many times is found in the original player list

However, `[tag]name` would be skipped if I explode for a space.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for regular expressions. You could have a certain number of regexps, and try matching them one after the other:

```
/**
 * function to return a tag given a playerName
 * @param  $playerName      string: player name, e.g. Coco [teamTag]
 * @return array            matching syntax (here 'brackets') and tag value (teamTag)
 */
function getTag($playerName) {

    // Allowed syntaxes

    $tagSyntaxes = array(
        'hash'    => '/#([\\w\\d]+)$/',
        'html'    => '/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/',
        'bracket' => '/[[](.*?)[]]/',
    );

    // One loop to rule them all
    foreach ($tagSyntaxes as $syntaxName => $regexp) {
        if (preg_match($regexp, $playerName, $gregs)) {
            // First syntax to match wins.
            return array(
                'syntax' => $syntaxName,
                'tag'    => $gregs[1])
            )
        }
    }
    // Loop exited with no match. Return a "dummy" tag
    return array('syntax' => 'none', 'tag' => null);
}
```

Comment: Have you missed a `/` at the end of the `'/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>'` string?